# Get the names of fighters from another table via join in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `matches` that stores information about every match that has happened in the UFC. Inside this table, I have three columns (fighter_a, fighter_b, winner) that are foreign keys, and reference the id from a `fighters` table. I would like to perform some type of query where I can get the `names` of the fighters, instead of just their ids. Reason being is I need to display the fighters name on a webpage, just having their id is useless to me.

What would the query look like in order to achieve this? I was thinking we could perform some type of join where each row gets three columns added to it, something like: `fighter_a_name`, `fighter_b_name`, and `winner_name`. I am still relatively new to SQL, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the `matches` table

[image]

Here is the `fighters` table

[image]

Comment: Is this MySQL or Postgresql? What is the SQL you're currently using to get these results (I assume just `SELECT * FROM ...`)? Typically, you can use a `join` of some kind to get data from related tables, or if you're planning on displaying this on a webpage, many frameworks have Relationship logic, etc. Either way, best to [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73417813/edit) with more details, what you've tried already, any errors, etc.

Comment: I am doing Postgres, I didn't know if it would matter, but I will update the question to be Postgres.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: This join is a little more complicated than just something simple. I understand how to do basic joins.

Comment: For a lot of things, MySQL vs Postgres doesn't matter, they are similar, but always best to tag it with the proper RDBMS for better focus  Thanks for the updates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple join will do the trick for you. Something like:

```
SELECT m.*, fa.name AS fighter_a_name, fb.name AS fighter_b_name, fw.name AS winner_name
FROM matches m
         JOIN fighters fa ON fa.id = m.fighter_a
         JOIN fighters fb ON fb.id = m.fighter_b
         JOIN fighters fw ON fw.id = m.winner;
```

You can join on the same table with different aliases when you have multiple references. Hope it helps.

Comment: Beautiful. It works!

Comment: I will accept this when the timer allows me to. =)